# Can someone explain the foreach() format for an array to me like I am 5

Tags: php, arrays, format

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val)
```

In the above example, if I had an array that prints:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [manufacturers_id] => 29
        [manufacturers_name] => Quiksilver
        [products_price] => 15.6000
        [products_quantity] => 1
        [products_cost] => 8.0000
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [manufacturers_id] => 29
        [manufacturers_name] => Quiksilver
        [products_price] => 4.6722
        [products_quantity] => 1
        [products_cost] => 2.4000
    )
```

What would be the correct value to insert into each of the values in the `foreach();` format. Assuming the `array` is just called `array`

Comment: Insert into what? Values into values? I don't get it :D

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $key => $item)
```

Lets you loop over array. Inside the loop `$key` will be given the value of the key and $item will be the actual array element. This will happen for each element.

To answer the question `What would be the correct value to insert into each of the values in the foreach(); format` the above will work. Inside you're loop you'll have access to key and value.

In your case you have an array of arrays. To loop over the first array you could use:

```
foreach($array as $item){

}
```

`$array` is your original array. Item would be

```
 Array
    (
        [manufacturers_id] => 29
        [manufacturers_name] => Quiksilver
        [products_price] => 15.6000
        [products_quantity] => 1
        [products_cost] => 8.0000
    )
```

In the first iteration. If you used the `foreach($array as $key => $item)` syntax then `$key` would be 0.

If you were to loop over the inside array (say the first one) then the keys and values for each loop would be:

```
    $key                     $item
    manufacturers_id   =>    29
    manufacturers_name =>    Quiksilver
    products_price     =>    15.6000
    products_quantity  =>    1
    products_cost      =>    8.0000
```

Comment: So in what situation would the use of the `=> $val` at the end of the `foreach();` be useful?

Comment: @Aleski You would use `foreach($array as $item)` if you only cared about the array elements. Like in your main array where the keys (`0` and '1') probably don't mean much. You would use `foreach($array as $key => $item)` for your inner array since the keys (like `products_cost` are useful).

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter should be your array, the second is the key or index of the array, while the third one is the value at this index. So for your data, you could use something like this (obviously, you can use any name for the parameters):

```
foreach ($array as $index => $manufacturer) {
    echo "ID = " . $manufacturer['manufacturers_id'];
    echo "Name = " . $manufacturer['manufacturers_name'];
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to work on each product/manufacturer.

For that, you would write a loop like this:

```
foreach($array as $product){
  //access product details here - Ex.
  print $product['products_price'];
}
```